# In javascript with variables and functions how would I write the syntax for if something is between a certain range? For example, between 0 and 0.34?

Tags: javascript

In javascript with variables and functions how would I write the syntax for if something is between a certain range? For example, between 0 and 0.34

Comment: you need to be more specific what you mean because the answer could be for instance: if (testVar > 0 && testVar < 0.34) { alert('found!'); }

Answer (score 2):

```
var lowerBounds = 0;
var upperBounds = .34;
var input = .24;
if(lowerBounds < input && input < upperBounds) {
      // input var is within specified bounds
}
```

Not sure the specifics of what you are doing, but a simple if statement should suffice.

Comment: this is how i wrote it if (computerChoice<0.33) {
  computerChoice=="rock" }
  else if(computerChoice <= 0.66)

Comment: is that the condition you want, because that if else if is not equivalent to .33 < x < .66

Answer (score 1):

Do 2 separate comparisons. Like this:

```
var x = 0.2;
if( 0 <= x && x <= 0.34) 
    console.log("x is in range");
```